# While loop for storing records with increasing tuples

Tags: python

I have created this code but it is only storing one value how can i modify it to store as many std records as many user wants...

```
while True:
    name=input('please provide name of a student')
    courses=[]
    stdrecord=()

    while True:
        course=input('please provide a course')
        courses.append(course)
        print(courses)
        ch_course=input('would you like to enter another course yes/no')
        if ch_course=='yes':
            continue
        else:
            stdrecord+=((name,courses))

            break
    ch_name=input('would you like to enter another record yes/no')
    if ch_name=='no':

        print (stdrecord)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a tuple to store the student record (round brackets), which is unmodifiable. Maybe try using a list (square brackets)?

Answer (score 0):

no matter i solved it by adding another while loop at top level with an empty list

```
while True:
     studentrec= []
```

and with

```
studentrec.append (stdrecord)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable, you can use a list or a dictionary.

Go through [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/tuple) to know more about tuples and other data-structures.

Replacing the tuple data-structure with another data-structure should solve your problem